# Examine $|x_n|$ of a Sequence; 3 cases

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $z=\sqrt(3)\frac{5}{12}+i\frac{5}{12}$ and let $b\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $x_n=(b\cdot z)^n$.
Now, I know that

- if $|bz|<1$, then $x_n \to 0$
- if $|bz|>1$, then $|x_n| \to \infty.$
- if $|bz|=1$, then $|x_n|=1$ for all $n$, hence $(x_n)$ is bounded.

and that $|z|=5/6$

**Question**

What does the second and third case actually tell me about $x_n$. I only know that if $|x_n|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$  then so does $x_n$.

For case 2; If $|x_n|\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ then what happens to $x_n$? Would that also diverge or do we actually not know this for sure. Is there some property for my sequence that allows me to draw some conclusion from this?

For case 3; If $|x_n|=1$ for all $n$ then $x_n$ should also be $1$ since we are taking powers of $1$ i.e $1^n$. That kind of makes sense for case 3.

Comment: fixed for modulus not abs.

Comment: Try writing $z$ in polar form ($z=re^{i\theta}$). It should all be much clearer.

Comment: @Blitzer found it to be $r=|z|=5/6$ and $\theta=\pi/6$. Still not quite sure. Could you elaborate on the relation of $|x_n|$ and $x_n$ when $z$ is in polar form? I think I am overseeing something

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what you are trying to ask. $|x_n|=|(bz)^n|=|b|^n|z|^n= |b|^n|(\frac56)^n= (\frac56 |b|)^n$. What is the outstanding question.